# Draw a (1/4) partial 3D cylinder in a quadrant

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, mathematical-optimization, constraint

Here is a code to draw a full cylinder $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$:

Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1/2]]

[image]

My question is that how do we draw a 1/4 of the cylinder, such that it only appears in the first quadrant in the y-z plane?

Edit: My version is Mathematica 11.1. Thank you.

Comment: It is always valuable to include your version number in your post if you are not currently running the most updated version. Can you, please, add this to your question text?

Comment: Edit: My version is Mathematica 11.1. Thank you.

Comment: One efficient way is to construct [BSplineSurface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineSurface.html) from tensor product. You might be interested in [my related post on Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2126761).

Comment: Terminology:  2D-space -> Quadrant, 3D-space ->Octant, Hyperspace -> Orthant or hyperoctant

Answer (score 6):

```
Region @ RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2, {0, Pi/2}], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]
```

[image]

```
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @
 RegionProduct[Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2, {0, Pi/2}], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]
```

[image]

If you need a graphics object:

```
RegionPlot3D[bdr, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.7], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

If we want to use `Graphics3D`,we need to `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}]; 
reg1 = 
 Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1/2]; 
Graphics3D[
 HighlightMesh[DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg]], 
  Style[1, None]], Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}];
reg1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1/2];
Region[Style[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg], Cyan], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much +1, this is the best answer (so far).

Comment: Is this compatible with Graphics3D? It seems not for "Graphics3D[Style[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg], Cyan], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]"

Comment: RegionIntersection seems to be not compatible with Graphics3D

Comment: @wonderich  `Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1/2], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.2}, {0, 1.2}}]` can't fill the other surfaces.

Comment: (My version is Mathematica 11.1. Thank you)